# progress 4gl OpenEdge abl delete file from directory

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How can you delete a file from a directory using OpenEdge ABL (progress-4gl) code?

I cannot find any code samples that get close to exemplifying this problem. I know how to output to value(path), and to input from value(path), but how is a delete accomplished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the 4GL OS-DELETE statement.

```
OS-DELETE value( "filename" ).
```

Comment: There is also OS-COMMAND, which can be handy if one needs to do a thing like TAKEOWN on the file before deletion.